# Google reCaptcha validation on NodeJs API running on AWS lambda

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, aws-lambda, google-oauth, recaptcha-v3

I'm trying to implement reCaptcha v3 to have an invisible captcha validation on my React-Native application.

My backend is running with services deployed on AWS Lambda with serverless framework. I managed to generate a token in react native with help of webview.
Something similar to [this](https://github.com/jarden-digital/react-native-recaptchav3).

In my API I came across multiple way to test the token but none worked.

First I tried to use `RecaptchaEnterpriseServiceClient` from `@google-cloud/recaptcha-enterprise`.
But I find out I have to setup `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` to point to a file with credentials. As I'm with lambda, didn't find a solution to have a file and a path to point to it.

Then I looked into the validation endpoint `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify`

But there I couldn't have a positive answer testing my tokens.
I tried both way to have keys :

- ReCaptcha enterprise from google cloud platform, that gives me only one key that I use in both my app to get the token and my API to check validity. In this case it return me `invalid-input-secret`
- ReCaptcha (standard?) witch give me two key, one for my website and one for my API. In this case it return me `incorrect-captcha-sol`

Here my code to call verify api :

```js
const secret = "secret=<MY-SECRET>";
const response = `&response=${body.captcha_token}`;
const remoteip = ip ? `&remoteip=${ip}` : "";

const url = `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?${secret}${response}${remoteip}`;

const { data } = await axios.post(url, {}, {
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8"
    }
});
```